# Importing data to R from Excel

Tags: r, excel

I have imported data from excel with:"read.xls" command, but I can not use this table, because the columns are not as vectors.
For example:

I have imported

```
Age Gender BMI Race Date.of.presentation
1 30 1 27 1 9/2/2014
2 58 2 28 1 9/30/2014
3 46 1 37 1 8/18/2014
4 43 2 27 1 8/25/2014
5 81 1 25 1 8/5/2014
6 41 2 24 1 7/29/2014
7 55 2 33 1 8/11/2014
8 62 2 35 1 9/9/2014
9 43 2 20 1 6/16/2014
```

But when I type "Age", it tells me: `Error: object 'Age' not found`

[image]

Comment: try excel$Age.  If that doesn't work, type str(excel) and post the results.  Also, google "r excel plot" to get some examples of working in R.

Comment: Cross posting without telling folks you're doing so is considered  rude. http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/58651-Importing-data-from-excel  I made the mistake myself at first too but the reason is (a) it messes with a searchable record of what helped and (b) people might be spending time to solve a problem that's already been solved.